# Subclassing basic datatypes in python

Tags: python

I want to subclass the `float` datatype in python3. My goal is to make a variable that returns its original value, +/- some range. Via other discussions, I know I can to this by:

```
class MonteCarloVariable(float):

    def __new__(cls, mean, std):
        val = np.random.normal(mean, std)
        return super(MonteCarloVariable, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

This then gives me:

```
>>> a = MonteCarloVariable(10, 2)
>>> a
7.5
```

What I would like, is that `a` changes value every time that it's used. i.e. :

```
>>> a
9.3
>>> a
11.6
```

... etc

If this isn't possible, how would I add a function to force a change? something like:

```
>>> a
7.5
>>> a.roll()
>>> a
10.1
```

The reason I'm trying to subclass `float` is that I don't want to redefine every `__add__` and `__sub__` type function.

Comment: How do define addition of two MonteCarloVariable instances with different standard deviations?

Comment: A `float` is immutable.

Comment: @AdityaBarve same as `np.random.normal(mean1, std1) + np.random.normal(mean2, std2)`